# how to rollback all SqlCommands which already executed with SqlTransaction?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, transactions, ado.net

I have the following code:

```
public void Execute(string Query, params SqlParameter[] Parameters)
{
    using (var Connection = new SqlConnection(Configuration.ConnectionString))
    {
        Connection.Open();

        using (var Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Connection))
        {
            if (Parameters.Length > 0)
            {
                Command.Parameters.Clear();
                Command.Parameters.AddRange(Parameters);
            }

            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

The method may be called 2 or 3 times for different queries but in same manner.

For example:

1. Insert an Employee
2. Insert Employee Certificates
3. Update Degree of Employee on another table  [ Fail can cause here. for example ]

If Point [3] fails, all already committed commands shouldn't execute and must be rolled back.

I know I can put `SqlTransaction` above and use `Commit()` method. But what about 3rd point if failed? I think point 3 only will rollback and other point 1,2 will not? How to solve this and what approach should I do??

Should I use `SqlCommand[]` arrays? What I should I do?

I only find similar question but in CodeProject:

[See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBRkg.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without changing your `Execute` method you can do this

```
    var tranOpts = new TransactionOptions()
    {
         IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
         Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout
    };

    using (var tran = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, tranOpts)
    {
       Execute("INSERT ...");
       Execute("INSERT ...");
       Execute("UPDATE ...");

       tran.Complete();
    }
```

SqlClient will cache the internal SqlConnection that is enlisted in the Transaction and reuse it for each call to Execute.  So you even end up with a local (not distributed) transaction.

This is all explained in the docs here: [System.Transactions Integration with SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/system-transactions-integration-with-sql-server)

Comment: And if so, does it secure and good performance ?? please explain more.

Comment: Only the queries in the TransactionScope will be committed or rolled back, and the performance is the same as using a TSQL BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT pair.

Comment: Man, you made my day. please forgive i want to know is TransactionScope better than Normal Connection.BeginTransaction() and Rollback() it ?? or its same as performance ?

Comment: It’s the same, normally.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do it.

The way that probably involves changing the least code and involves the least complexity is to chain multiple SQL statements into a single query. It's perfectly fine to build a string for the `Query` argument that runs more than one statement, including `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, `COMMIT`, and (if needed) `ROLLBACK`. Basically, keep a whole stored procedure in your C# code. This also has the nice benefit of making it easier to use version control with your procedures.

But it still feels kind of hackish.

One way to reduce that effect is marking the `Execute()` method ***private***. Then, have an additional method in the class for each query. In this way, the long SQL strings are isolated, and when you're using the database it feels more like using a local API. For more complicated applications, this might instead be a whole separate assembly with a few types managing logical functional areas, where the core methods like `Exectue()` are `internal`. This is a good idea anyway, regardless of how you end up supporting transactions.

And speaking of procedures, stored procedures are also a perfectly fine way to handle this. Have one stored procedure to do all the work, and call it when ready.

Another option is overloading the method to accept multiple queries and parameter collections:

```
public void Execute(string TransactionName, string[] Queries, params SqlParameter[][] Parameters)
{
    using (var Connection = new SqlConnection(Configuration.ConnectionString))
    using (var Transaction = new SqlTransaction(TransactionName))
    {
        connection.Transaction = Transaction;
        Connection.Open();
        try 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Queries.Length; i++)
            {
                using (var Command = new SqlCommand(Queries[i], Connection))
                {
                    command.Transaction = Transaction;
                    if (Parameters[i].Length > 0)
                    {
                        Command.Parameters.Clear();
                        Command.Parameters.AddRange(Parameters);
                    }                
                    Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            Transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Transaction.Rollback();
            throw; //I'm assuming you're handling exceptions at a higher level in the code
        }
    }
}
```

Though I'm not sure how the `params` keyword works with an array of arrays... I've just not tried that option, but something along these lines would work. The weakness here is also that it's not trivial to have a later query depend on a result from an earlier query, and even queries with no parameter would still need a Parameters array as a placeholder.

A final option is extending the type holding your `Execute()` method to support transactions. The trick here is it's common (and desirable) to have this type be `static`, but supporting transactions requires re-using common connection and transaction objects. Given the implied long-running nature of a transaction, you have to support more than one at a time, which means both instances and implementing `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Configuration.ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                SqlTransaction transaction;
                connection.Open();
                transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("Transaction");

                command.Connection = connection;
                command.Transaction = transaction;

                try
                {
                    if (Parameters.Length > 0)
                    {
                        command.Parameters.Clear();
                        command.Parameters.AddRange(Parameters);
                    }
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex2)
                    {
                       //trace
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: This is a correct answer but could use some more detail. What would it look like if there were multiple commands?

Comment: @MahdiAnjam Sql Server already uses implicit transaction. There's no reason to ever use this code with just one SqlCommand object. The whole point is you would run a series of command in a row with the same transaction.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That's true if (as in this case) the command isn't a stored procedure containing multiple updates. If this was a stored procedure this would work, although we'd never do it. We'd put the transaction in the procedure. But since the OP asked about executing multiple commands is makes sense to show how the answer applies when executing multiple commands.